# EasyRec vs PredictionIO vs Apache Mahout

Tags: java, machine-learning, predictionio

I would like to develop real-time analytic tools for my website ( engineering project). My application will be written in JAVA-EE and maven. I have found three tools (topic). I knew that PredictionIO is using Apache Mahout. But I can't decide which algorithm use. If someone knew what are the pros and cons of this algorithms let them write. What do you think, which will be the best ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version 0.8 of PredictionIO the stack has been rebuilt on Apache Spark and now integrates [MLlib](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.1/mllib-guide.html) library. It is hard to advise about pros and cons of different algos without knowing your use case and in more detail feel free to ask on our PredictionIO support forum.

Databricks (creators of Apache Spark) also have some [performance benchmarks for MLlib versus Mahout](https://databricks.com/blog/2014/07/23/scalable-collaborative-filtering-with-spark-mllib.html).